How to show a widget in a popover in flutter? I got blank screen

i get blank screen when i click a icon button

Blank Screen on pop up
I tried to follow the example on Flutter Package, but I couldn't find my mistake. I want to make some columns pop up, but they do not appear and I still get a black screen. Can someone help me?

please share code of SettingsMenu for better understanding

It looks like the console shows some error messages. Maybe it will tell you what's going wrong

don't you have to await the call to showPopover?

Try to wrap the popover in a widget as indicated in the discussion https://github.com/minikin/popover/issues/54
It works for me after wrapping in a widget like this:
"main.dart/popMenu.dart/popMenu"
class PopMenu extends StatelessWidget {
  PopMenu({super.key});

@override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return GestureDetector(
          child: Icon(
            Icons.more_vert,
            color: Appt.color2,
          ),
          onTap: () async {
            await showPopover(
              backgroundColor: Appt.background,
              context: context,
              constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 70),
              transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 150),
              width: 150,
              direction: PopoverDirection.bottom,
              bodyBuilder: (_) => Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    InkWell(
                      child: Text(
                        "Today",
                        style: Appt.txtS22CL2,
                      ),
                    ),
                    InkWell(
                      child: Text(
                        "Today",
                        style: Appt.txtS22CL2,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
}
      }

"main.dart/mainScreen"
SizeBox(
 PopMenu(),
)


this answer lacks an explanation of the problem.

The issue with the popover positioning is due to the context being used. Instead of using the context of the whole page, you need to get the context of the button itself to position the popover correctly. Here is an approach I used to ensure the popover is positioned relative to my button.
1 Wrap the button with a Builder widget to get its context.
2 Use the context of the Builder widget to show the popover.
                  Builder(
                    builder: (context) {
                      return ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            showPopover(
                              context: context,
                              bodyBuilder: (context) =>
                              const Center(
                                  child: Text(
                                "Hello Flutter!",
                              )),
                              width: 200,
                              height: 100,
                              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                              radius: 12,
                              direction: PopoverDirection.top,
                            );
                          },
                          child: const Text("Show popup"));
                    },
                  )

